# Increment a counter from batch step in Mule

Tags: mule, batch-processing

I have a situation where I am using Batch to process the records.

**Each records contains a sub-records which I have to sum up for all records.**

For now what I am doing is at each batch step,I am reading the no. of sub-records & storing it in some flow variable say "counter". In this Batch step only I am adding this counter to another flow variable say "total_count". But at this total_count does not remain persistent. For each record, this total_count set to 0 as it is been initialized at the start of the flow. I set total_count as session variable & Property as well. but It gives same result.

I want total count this sub-record. What approach I should use? How can I increase the value of total_count as per each record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to persist the count in record variable.It should be available and persist across batch records.Please refer link below

[Record variable](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/record-variable)

Comment: But I have to initialized that recordVar which can be at the start of the batch step only. so, it will reset to same at each batch step.